# How to only give MUI Switch border style when it is checked?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is the [demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicswitches-material-demo-forked-0dcv2?file=/demo.js). Right now I give root a border style. However, I want to remove the border style when the switch is checked. How would I do this? Thanks for the help!

```
import * as React from "react";
import Switch from "@mui/material/Switch";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const label = { inputProps: { "aria-label": "Switch demo" } };

const CustomSwitch = withStyles({
  root: {
    width: "40px",
    height: "20px",
    padding: "0px",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    marginRight: "8px",
    border: "1px solid #606060",
    position: "relative"
  },

  colorSecondary: {
    "&.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track": {
      backgroundColor: "#05756C"
    },
    "&.Mui-checked": {
      color: "white"
    }
  },
  thumb: {
    position: "absolute",
    width: "12px",
    height: "12px"
  },
  track: {
    backgroundColor: "transparent"
  },
  switchBase: {
    color: "#606060",
    "&$checked": {
      // color: 'white!important',
    }
  }
})(Switch);

export default function BasicSwitches() {
  return (
    <div>
      <CustomSwitch {...label} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the border from the parent (`SwitchBase`) and put it in the track component inside so it can be targeted by CSS selector when the state of the sibling element changes:

```
root: {
  ...
  // border: '1px solid #606060', // <-------------------- comment this line
},
track: {
  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  borderRadius: '10px',
  border: '1px solid #606060',
  height: 'auto',
  opacity: 1,
},
switchBase: {
  color: '#606060',
  '&.Mui-checked + $track': {
    border: 'none',
  },
},
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Since you're using v5, you shouldn't use `withStyles` anymore, it is deprecated and will be removed in v6. Here is the equivalent demo in v5 using `styled` instead.

[image: Codesandbox Demo]